# VS CODE: How to configure launch.json for javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, debugging

I would like to start using the Run and Debug view in VS Code. But I have difficulty to configure it. All my breakpoints are unbounded (the hollow circles), as you can see in this snapshot.

[image]

I am developing on a virtual machine. This is the home screen of my project.

[image]

Obviously, I am using Goole Chrome. The link of my project is "http://cstl-dms02.dev.corp.boldbrick.com/SitePages/Home.aspx". But this not a real URL, it just looks like it. It probably runs on localhost at "localhost:4411" as you can see in the Sources tab.

This is what I have in my launch.json file. But none of these two options work.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:4421",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://cstl-dms02.dev.corp.boldbrick.com/SitePages/Home.aspx",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/"
    }
  ]
}
```

I will be grateful for any suggestions.